# Let $G$ a connected graph. If every vertex of $G$ has even degree

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ a connected graph. If every vertex of $G$ has even degree, then for any vertex $v\in V(G)$, $$\omega(G-v)\le\dfrac{\delta(v)}{2}$$ Where, $\delta(v)$ denote degree of $v$ and $\omega(G-v)$ is the number of connected components of $G-v$.

I am looking for a way to obtain that inequality, but I still have no results.

I consider two cases:

1. $v$ is not a cut vertex. In this case the result is satisfied.
2. $v$ is a cut vertex. In this case I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

Let $v \in V(G)$. Since every vertex of $G$ has even degree, $G$ is Eulerian, i.e. $G$ has an Euler cycle $C$. We can say $C$ starts (and thus ends) at $v$. Starting at $v$, we travel a sequence of vertices, say $A_1$, along $C$, and must eventually reach $v$ once more. This occurs $\delta(v)/2$ many times (why?). This gives us $A_1,A_2,\dots, A_{\delta(v)/2}$, where $(G-v)[A_i]$ is a connected component of $G-v$. If the $A_i$ are pairwise disjoint, then we achieve equality, i.e. $\omega(G-v) = \frac{\delta(v)}{2}$. An example of this is a number of cycles joined at the same vertex such as the [Friendship Graph.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph) Otherwise, the inequality is strict (why?).

I've left out *some* detail, but this is the gist of it. Note by $G[A]$ we mean the subgraph of $G$ induced by the vertex subset $A$.